# Кроссбраузерный websocket

Tags: javascript, html5, websocket

Как сделать надежную поддержку websocket на тех браузерах где эта технология не работает?
Вычитал что есть несколько сторонних библиотек. Но вот что из них выбрать и стоит ли их использовать не знаю.
Что посоветуете, что зарекомендовало себя как надежно работающий вариант?
И желательно с примером Как работать с этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) имеет различные транспорты: вебсокеты, лонгполлинг, флешсокеты. Если ваш сервер на node.js, то это лучший выбор.

Comment: Сервер работает на Python Django. Но мне кажется это не принципиально.

Comment: @АбрамовАлексей всё верно, для питона тоже есть реализация.

Comment: @Абрамов Алексей https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/tree/master/src/main/example/web-socket-js на флэше, те браузеры, что не поддерживают ws - поддерживают флэш